# Save Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne boolean return value to variable

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do I save the return value from Selction.Find.Execute to a boolean variable.  This is my code snippet and I get a compile error for "myBool = Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne"

```
Dim myBool As Boolean
myBool = True

Do While myBool
    Selection.Find.Text = "myText"
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = replacementText //More logic to change this variable not shown
    myBool = Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
Loop
```

Basically, I have a loop to do a search and replace but I'm trying to stop the loop once no more search texts exists.

Comment: If you use `Replace:=wdReplaceAll` there is no need for a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use it as a function (that returns something) then you need to include the parenthesis.

```
Dim myBool As Boolean
myBool = True

Do While myBool
    Selection.Find.Text = "myText"
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = replacementText //More logic to change this variable not shown
    myBool = Selection.Find.Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceOne) 
Loop
```

Timothy also makes a valid point about using `Replace:=wdReplaceAll` instead. If you can avoid using a loop, it's always going to be better/faster, but that was not the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you set:

```
.Wrap = wdFindStop
```

there is no need for the test. For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = InputBox("What is the Text to Find")
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    i = i + 1
    'Do something
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox i & " instances found."
End Sub
```

And, if you want to limit the process to a selected range:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, Rng As Range
Set Rng = Selection.Range
With Selection.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = InputBox("What is the Text to Find")
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    If .InRange(Rng) = False Then Exit Do
    i = i + 1
    'Do something
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox i & " instances found."
End Sub
```